# fb like button creates a white background on page onload in all ie versions

Tags: html, css, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [fb like button creates a white background on page onload in all ie versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438502/fb-like-button-creates-a-white-background-on-page-onload-in-all-ie-versions)

Im using the code   to add a facebook like button to my page, when the page loads there is a noticeable white background in ie before the button actually appears, is there a way of removing this?