# fb like button creates a white background on page onload in all ie versions

Tags: html, css, facebook

I have added the facebook like button `<fb:like href="http://mysite.com" class="myFacebook" layout="button_count" ></fb:like>`.

When my page loads in any ie there is a noticeable white background before the like button appears, is there any way of removing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the `iframe` loading its content.

You could set `visibility: hidden` on the `iframe`, and then show it once it has loaded to avoid this.

Comment: How do you know when the iFrame is loaded?  I managed to use $('#fblike iframe').ready() to catch the ready event, but its not quite loaded at that point, and .load() doesn't seem to work (it never gets called).

Comment: @AlexBlack `onload="this.style.visibility = 'visible';"`

Answer (score 0):

You should set `allowtransparency="true"` in `iFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply hide the container with CSS and then display it once the iframe has loaded, this can be done two ways:

```
<style>#fblike { visibility:hidden; }</style> /* Hide container */

<script>
FB.XFBML.parse(document, function(){
   $('#fblike').css({'visibility':'visible'}); /* Show container once loaded */
});
</script>
```

If you are not using this FB.XFBML.parse() function then you can subscribe an event when everything has rendered instead:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'APP_ID',
            xfbml: true
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render',
            function () {
                 $('#fblike').css({'visibility':'visible'}); /* Show container once loaded */
            }
        );
    };
```

Took me a while to find this all out! Here is a link to where I found my solution: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Answer (score 0):

I had to do like this to make it work

```
.fb_iframe_widget_fluid{
    background:none !important;

    //If you want no padding and no margin
    padding:0 !important; 
    margin:0 !important;
}
```